# xtick label formatting in pandas when using time index

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am plotting a time series in pandas and the index is of type time (meaning it does not contain the date information). What I want to do is format the xtick labels to only show the hour and not minutes and seconds.

```
import datetime
import random
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pylab as plt
%matplotlib inline

#generate a list of random datetime.times
random_time = lambda: (datetime.datetime.strptime("00:00:00", '%H:%M:%S') + datetime.timedelta(minutes=random.randrange(1440))).time()
times = [random_time() for x in range(20)]

#create data frame
df = pd.DataFrame({'times': times, 'counts': [random.randrange(10) for x in range(len(times))]})
df.set_index('times', inplace=True)

df.plot()
#I want tick labels at sensible places, only two here as illustration
custom_tick_locs = [datetime.time(hour=8), datetime.time(hour=16)]
plt.xticks(custom_tick_locs)
```

Which produces the following plot:

[image]

**My question is: how can I format the xtick labels to only show the hour? (Or any other format in general?)**

I know that using datetime (including both and time) would make things a lot easier. However, since I'm overlaying data from several days I am using only the time. Obviously there might be a way to do that overlaying (so that 1pm is at the same x-position for all days) so if I'm missing an easy solution for that please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `strftime` to compute the labels amd pass them to `plt.xticks` along with the tick locs:

```
custom_tick_locs = [datetime.time(hour=8), datetime.time(hour=16)]
custom_tick_labels = map(lambda x: x.strftime('%H'), custom_tick_locs)
plt.xticks(custom_tick_locs, custom_tick_labels)
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I'm looking for since it allows for a lot of flexibility in formatting!

Answer (score 5):

You can do all this automatically with the [Matplotlib date API](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.HourLocator):

```
from matplotlib.dates import HourLocator, DateFormatter

ax = df.plot() # don't throw away the Axes object
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(HourLocator(interval=2)) # tick every two hours
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%H'))
```

The `DateFormatter` accepts any [strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) string. The advantage of using the formatters and locators is that you don't have to manually deal with the Axes limits. There's lots of different locators and formatters in `matplotlib.dates` for date and time and in `matplotlib.ticker` for numbers in general.

Comment: Wish I'd known about this part of the matplotlib library before, I've spent way too much time over the years trying to deal with axis ticks and labels manually.